# Bash script regex on parameter

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
REGEX='(www\.)?\w*\.\w*'                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
echo "$1" | grep -P -o $REGEX                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
DOMAIN="$1" | grep -P -o $REGEX                                                                                                                                                                                                        

echo $DOMAIN
```

What I want to achieve is to get the domain from a full URL.

If I give as parameter the: `http://example.com/` then I need the example.com

The first echo works.

How could I pass that expression into a variable? I need to pass later the `DOMAIN` to a script.

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."

Comment: assuming the objective is to capture the results of the `echo | grep` in the variable `DOMAIN` ... `DOMAIN=$(echo "$1" | grep -P -o $REGEX)`

Comment: @markp-fuso Thank you, it should be an answer....

Comment: @vaso123 `var=$(command)` is a pretty basic concept in (unix/linux) shell scripting; not really worthy of an answer; I *would* recommend reviewing the linked 'duplicates' for other, more efficient, methods of parsing a string; good luck